# The response has been already committed. Could not send the response to another URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using spring security 4.2.3.RELEASE in my spring mvc application. I have login success handler to handle the actions upon successful authentication.

Here is my LoginSuccessHandler.java

```html
package com.application.security;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

import com.application.util.CommonUtils;


@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class LoginSuccessHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    
    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoginSuccessHandler.class); 
    
    @Autowired
    Environment environment;
    
    @Autowired
    CommonUtils commonUtils;
    
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {
        int sessionTimeOut = Integer.parseInt(environment.getRequiredProperty("server.session.timeout").toString().trim());
        request.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(sessionTimeOut);
        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
        CustomUser user = commonUtils.getLoggedInUserDetails();
        if(user != null) {
            if(!user.isPasswordReset()) {
                response.sendRedirect("changePassword");    
            }
        }
        logger.info("Successfully LoggedIn......");
    }
}
```

Everything is working fine until the line
`response.sendRedirect("changePassword");`  execute. This line is generating the below error.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendRedirect() after the response has been committed

I know that the response been already committed when the application calls `super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);`

Do i need to override this super class to resolve this issue? Or any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because response already has been committed by `super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);`

but the time you are using `response.sendRedirect("changePassword");` response has been already sent.

see [this for more info](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.6.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler.html#onAuthenticationSuccess-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse-org.springframework.security.core.Authentication-)

Note : This line should be the last line of the method `super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);`